# Avoiding "one-to-one" mapping of arrays in bash v3.2

Tags: arrays, bash

I am looking for a way to avoid this "one-to-one" mapping in my arrays. I have looked into associative arrays / hash tables but I am running bash version 3.2 and those are only supported in version 4.0+. Below is a sample of how the code functions now.

```
#!/bin/bash

arr_fruit=(orange apple banana kiwi watermelon)
arr_color=(orange red yellow green pink)

i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#arr_fruit[@]} ]; do
     echo -e "${arr_fruit[$i]} | ${arr_color[$i]}
     i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Comment: What are you trying to *do* with these pairs? Are the possible values for the pairs arbitrary or do they have some limitations you can use?

Comment: The end goal would be pulling the arr_color values from a database according to arr_fruit... But the problem would be the order they get pulled in and possible mismatches in the array index..

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to a more recent version of Bash? Bash 3.2 is getting a little bit old now: released in 2006… (another option is to use another programming language).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That's the version shipped with OS X. I assume that might be why. That or older versions of CentOS.

Comment: Can you explain what that means exactly? If you are pulling a set of values from a database based on an existing array what does this have to do with mapping arrays to one another? Or did you mean pulling the values from the db in bulk and *then* doing something with the mapped pairs? Can you explain *in detail* what your actual end goal is here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the full unix toolkit available to you

```
$ echo -e ${arr_fruit[@]}"\n"${arr_color[@]} | 
  tr ' ' '\n' | 
  pr -2ts" | "

orange | orange
apple | red
banana | yellow
kiwi | green
watermelon | pink
```